# Programmatically set Toolpart layout

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, toolpart

I am following this tutorial for creating a tool part: http://www.dhirajranka.com/?p=420

What I still have to understand is how to:
1) add a title to the custom tool part
2) adjust the various components (buttons dropdown lists etc)

I have been spoiled with the designer view but now that I cannot use it I am a bit lost.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this line to your webpart's properties:

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false), WebBrowsable(true), WebDescription("Set the list name to use."), WebDisplayName("List Name"), Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
public string ListName{ 
    get{return customListName;}
    set{customListName = value;}
}
```

This works, right now I have this running over my SharePoint.

Best regards!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Me Being a bit dim, could you put it more in teh context of the example in the link?  cheers.

Comment: Hey dude! I have been a little busy lately, do you still need more context in this example? If so, I'd gladly do this!